# Array problem: Assignment to expression with array type

Tags: arrays, c

i'm sure it's simple but i can get out of this; the scope is only to do a grid for naval battle.

```
#define dim 3 
#define num_navi 3 

int batt[dim][dim]; 
int battv[dim][dim];
int r,c,i,j,cont;



void InizializzaGriglia()
{
for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
for(j=0; j<dim; j++)
{
battv[j]=0;
batt[j]=0;
}
}
```

The debugger says that in the lines in the for cycle there is an error in the assignment to expression with array type.
Reading some guides, it was suggested to declare the array as a const, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

Can you please help me?

Comment: `battv[i][j] = 0;` perhaps? `battv[j]` is an array of 4 elements.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: do not use global variables, prefer to pass pointers around.

Comment: first of all format your code

Comment: I would advise against learning C by reading some random guides on the internet. Get a good textbook.

Comment: @pmg 4? Really?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: was 4 before changes to the original question.

Comment: @pmg yes i'm working on it right now, sorry for the changes.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. it's a guide provided from my university teacher, should be right i guess

Comment: I think this site has one or two examples of materials provided by educational institutions being of dubious quality. If your guide suggests putting variables outside of functions, I would treat everything it says with great suspicion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant assign arrays (and battv[n] is a one dimentional array with value). You can only assign the elements of the array (assuming that they are not arrays as well)

```
void InizializzaGriglia()
{
    for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
        for(j=0; j<dim; j++)
        {
            battv[i][j]=0;
            batt[i][j]=0;
        }
}
```

when you only zero the array you can use memset function

```
void InizializzaGriglia1()
{
    memset(battv, 0, sizeof(battv));
    memset(batt, 0, sizeof(batt));
}
```

or bad non portable way

```
void InizializzaGriglia_notportable_silly()
{
    struct str
    {
        int array[dim][dim];
    }*ptr = (void *)battv;

    *ptr = (struct str){0};
    ptr = (void *)batt;
    *ptr = (struct str){0};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int battv[dim][dim];` defines `battv` to be a two-dimensional array: an array of arrays of `int`.

To refer to an `int` in such a two-dimensional array, you need two dimensions: `battv[i][j]` refers to the `int` in row `i` and column `j`:

- `battv` refers to the array of arrays of `int`.
- `battv[i]` refers to one of the arrays of `int` in `battv`.
- `battv[i][j]` refers to one of the `int` in one of the arrays of `battv`.

To set an element to zero, use `battv[i][j] = 0;`, not `battv[i] = 0;`.